# Как правильно сверстать эту секцию с картой?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно что контент находиться в ограничивающем контейнере, контейнер равен 1170px,как мне правильно прописать вот этот серый бэкграунд и карту чтобы они не ограничивались по ширине контейнера а были растянуты на весь вьюпорт?

Comment: Кто поможет уже голову сломал?